# Not able to extract value from the response and use it in next request using JSON extractor

Tags: jmeter

Here is the reponse and i want to extract the id from it

{"status":"success","data":{"name":"chirag","salary":"1000","age":"30","id":82}}

this is how i am trying to extract:

[image]

then use it in the next request like this:

[image]

Update:
When i use this in this in the next request - `api/v1/delete/${id}`, I get this error:

```
Thread Name:Delete Employee 5-1
Sample Start:2020-07-19 11:27:54 WEST
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:1115
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:1115
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 47: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/delete/${id}
```

Comment: Try `${id}` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Extract... modify the "json path expression" as:

`$.data.id` OR `$..id`

Then in subsequent request, correct the path:

`/api/v1/update/${id}`

Comment: i get this error: Thread Name:Delete Employee 5-1
Sample Start:2020-07-19 11:27:54 WEST
Load time:0
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:1115
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:1115
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in path at index 47: http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/delete/${id}

Comment: I added this error in my question as well, please take a look

Comment: Add `http` in `Protocol[HTTP]:` field

Comment: Both request `from` where you're extracting value and passing `to` next request should be under the same thread group.

Comment: Thank you, ahh didn't realize that mistake. It works now